# I'm unable to call Laravel Cart methods statically from controller

Tags: laravel, cart

I'm trying to set up this shopping cart library in Laravel, but I keep getting `Non-static method Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::add() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context` https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

here's my controller code:

```
public function getCart(){
    $cartCollection = Cart::getContent(); 
    return response()->json($cartCollection->toArray());
}


public function updateCart( Request $request, $id ){
    $input = $request->all(); 
    Cart::update($id, array_except($input, array('_token')));
}   

public function addToCart( Request $request ){
    $input= $request->all(); 
    Cart::add(array_except($input, array('_token')));
}

public function removeFromCart( $id ){
    Cart::remove($id);
}
```

my confusion is that the documentation for this library says that you should be calling the methods statically. I also tried using the dependency ejection method, and that threw a different error. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm pretty new to Laravel so forgive me if this is a dumb oversight.

also I fallowed all the steps to set up this library, including adding it to the App.php providers array and the aliases array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of calling the static methods on the `Darryldecode\Cart\Cart` class you should do that on the facade of the packages. In your case that probably just means removing a `use Darryldecode\Cart\Cart;` statement in your controller.

Because the controller is probably inside a namespace of it's own you now have to either reference it by `\Cart` or add `use Cart` to make sure the alias is used for the calls.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades) to learn more about Laravel Facades and how they work

Comment: I got it... I changed it to use Cart; Thank you so much!!!! That worked like a charm.